# How can I monitor cellular internet connectivity and restart modem if needed?

Tags: c#

I have a windows tablet (win 7) with a service I'm running on it that sends gps coordinates to a remote web server.

Sometimes in the area there is no 3g reception (the bars are near empty) but the network is still connected.

I want to be able to monitor the internet reception and if there is none to reset the cellular modem (its a sierra one if its matter)

What route will you recommend me to go using c# ?